# nullpointer LocationManager getLatitude

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, gps

I'm getting a null pointer exception on the line that calls get latitude in my GPSTracker class. Any ideas why? I'm using a mobile device as well, not DDMS. I've done a `System.out.println(gps.getLatitude())` and it indeed does return null, but I can't figure out why. The GPS on my phone is turned on as well

Here is my class

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener{

    private final Context mContext;
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;   
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;   
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location;
    Double latitude;
    Double longitude;

    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; //10 meters 
    private static final long  MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; //1 minute  
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker (Context context){
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            //getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            System.out.println(location.getLatitude());

            if(!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled){
                //no network provider is enabled
            } else{
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled){
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if(locationManager != null){
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if(location != null){
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (isGPSEnabled){
                    if(location == null){
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if(locationManager != null){
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if(location != null){
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return location;
    }
    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            System.out.println(latitude);
            return 0.0;
        }
        System.out.println(latitude);
        return latitude;
    }
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            System.out.println(longitude);
            return 0.0;
        }
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show setting alert dialog
     */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        //Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");
        //Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings and enable GPS?"); 
        //Setting Icon to Dialog
        //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);
        //On Pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        //on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        //Showing alert message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location){       
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){        
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){     
    }
    @Override 
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){        
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0){
        return null;
    }   
}
```

Where I parse my the JSON

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {
      static InputStream is = null;
      static JSONObject jObj = null;
      static String json = "";
      // constructor
      public JSONParser() {
      }
      public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String myurl) {
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
          // defaultHttpClient
            URL url = new URL(myurl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("HttpConnection", "The response is: " + response);
            is = conn.getInputStream();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        try {
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
              is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          String line = null;
          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "n");
          }
          is.close();
          json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
          jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
          Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
      }
    }
```

My main activity

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        public TextView weather = null;
        public TextView summary = null;
        public TextView icon = null;
        public JSONObject currentTemperature = null;
        public String temperature = "";
        public String weatherSummary = "";
        public String weatherIcon = "";
        public GPSTracker gps;
        public double latitude = 0;
        public double longitude = 0;
        public String myUrl;
        public TextView latitudeView = null;
        public TextView longitudeView = null;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            weather = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weather);
            summary = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weather_summary);
            icon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.string_icon);           
            // we will using AsyncTask during parsing 
            new AsyncTaskParseJson().execute();

            gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
            myUrl = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/5530508d3568e57848d53bf10cfade1f/35.9033,-79.0440";
                //gps.getLatitude() + "," + gps.getLongitude();

             double lat = gps.getLatitude();
             double longitude = gps.getLatitude();
             latitudeView.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
             longitudeView.setText(String.valueOf(longitude));
        }

       /* public String convertLatitude(){
            latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            String latitude2 = Double.toString(latitude);

            return latitude2;
        }*/

       /* public String convertLongitude(){
            longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            String longitude2 = Double.toString(longitude);

            return longitude2;
        }*/

        //do in background method to call JSON Parser
        public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";       

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0){

               try {


                    // instantiate our json parser
                    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
                    // get json string from url
                    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(myUrl);


                    JSONObject current = json.getJSONObject("currently");
                    temperature = current.getString("temperature");

                    weatherSummary = current.getString("summary");
                    weatherIcon = current.getString("icon");               

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
            return myUrl;


            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {

                 weather.setText(temperature);
                 summary.setText(weatherSummary);
                 icon.setText(weatherIcon);

            }
        }
    }
```

And my LogCat

```
07-12 15:13:31.373: W/System.err(32167): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-12 15:13:31.378: W/System.err(32167):    at rafa.weatherapp.GPSTracker.getLocation(GPSTracker.java:42)
07-12 15:13:31.378: W/System.err(32167):    at rafa.weatherapp.GPSTracker.<init>(GPSTracker.java:33)
07-12 15:13:31.378: W/System.err(32167):    at rafa.weatherapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
07-12 15:13:31.378: W/System.err(32167):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
07-12 15:13:31.378: W/System.err(32167):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
07-12 15:13:31.378: W/System.err(32167):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
07-12 15:13:31.378: W/System.err(32167):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
07-12 15:13:31.378: W/System.err(32167):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
07-12 15:13:31.378: W/System.err(32167):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
07-12 15:13:31.378: W/System.err(32167):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-12 15:13:31.378: W/System.err(32167):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
07-12 15:13:31.378: W/System.err(32167):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
07-12 15:13:31.378: W/System.err(32167):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 15:13:31.378: W/System.err(32167):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-12 15:13:31.378: W/System.err(32167):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
07-12 15:13:31.378: W/System.err(32167):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
07-12 15:13:31.378: W/System.err(32167):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-12 15:13:31.378: I/System.out(32167): null
07-12 15:13:31.378: D/AndroidRuntime(32167): Shutting down VM
07-12 15:13:31.378: W/dalvikvm(32167): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41886c08)
07-12 15:13:31.378: W/System.err(32167): java.net.MalformedURLException
07-12 15:13:31.378: W/System.err(32167):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:152)
07-12 15:13:31.378: W/System.err(32167):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
07-12 15:13:31.378: W/System.err(32167):    at rafa.weatherapp.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:29)
07-12 15:13:31.378: W/System.err(32167):    at rafa.weatherapp.MainActivity$AsyncTaskParseJson.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:76)
07-12 15:13:31.378: E/AndroidRuntime(32167): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 15:13:31.378: E/AndroidRuntime(32167): Process: rafa.weatherapp, PID: 32167
07-12 15:13:31.378: E/AndroidRuntime(32167): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{rafa.weatherapp/rafa.weatherapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-12 15:13:31.378: E/AndroidRuntime(32167):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
07-12 15:13:31.378: E/AndroidRuntime(32167):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
07-12 15:13:31.378: E/AndroidRuntime(32167):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
07-12 15:13:31.378: E/AndroidRuntime(32167):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
07-12 15:13:31.378: E/AndroidRuntime(32167):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-12 15:13:31.378: E/AndroidRuntime(32167):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
07-12 15:13:31.378: E/AndroidRuntime(32167):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
07-12 15:13:31.378: E/AndroidRuntime(32167):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 15:13:31.378: E/AndroidRuntime(32167):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-12 15:13:31.378: E/AndroidRuntime(32167):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
07-12 15:13:31.378: E/AndroidRuntime(32167):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
07-12 15:13:31.378: E/AndroidRuntime(32167):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-12 15:13:31.378: E/AndroidRuntime(32167): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-12 15:13:31.378: E/AndroidRuntime(32167):    at rafa.weatherapp.GPSTracker.getLatitude(GPSTracker.java:92)
07-12 15:13:31.378: E/AndroidRuntime(32167):    at rafa.weatherapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
07-12 15:13:31.378: E/AndroidRuntime(32167):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
07-12 15:13:31.378: E/AndroidRuntime(32167):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
07-12 15:13:31.378: E/AndroidRuntime(32167):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
07-12 15:13:31.378: E/AndroidRuntime(32167):    ... 11 more
07-12 15:13:31.383: W/ActivityManager(2431):   Force finishing activity rafa.weatherapp/.MainActivity
07-12 15:13:31.388: W/System.err(32167):    at rafa.weatherapp.MainActivity$AsyncTaskParseJson.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
07-12 15:13:31.388: W/System.err(32167):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-12 15:13:31.388: W/System.err(32167):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-12 15:13:31.388: W/System.err(32167):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-12 15:13:31.388: W/System.err(32167):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-12 15:13:31.388: W/System.err(32167):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-12 15:13:31.388: W/System.err(32167):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-12 15:13:31.388: E/Buffer Error(32167): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
07-12 15:13:31.393: E/JSON Parser(32167): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

Comment: Did you set appropriate permissions in your manifest?   ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Comment: i've ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Comment: is getLongitude returning null as well? or jsut latitude?

Comment: both are returning null

Comment: And the location object is definitely not null?  It seems pretty weird if `getLastKnownLocation()` is returning a non null location but both longitude and latitude are null.  Can you log longitude and latitude in your `onLocationChanged()` for the location thats passed in to see if that is ever getting called with valid location?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the location of the permissions are in the appropriate place within the manifest. It may help if you post the contents of your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

replace all

```
System.out.println("")
```

with

```
Log.d("", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing:

```
   gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
```

with

```
 gps = new GPSTracker(getApplicationContext());
```

also

```
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                if(locationManager != null){
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if(location != null){
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
```

on getLastKnownLocation might be null if you've never actually gotten a location before. I would suggest putting the latitude = location.getLatitude() calls into the onLocationChanged method so you guarantee you are getting the correct location, asynchronously.